# How to format curl result into jq then redirect to Vim?

Tags: vimscript, neovim

I am trying to pipe `curl` result to `jq` then to Vim, but nothing happens.

If I follow the below method I get the desired result:

```
curl --location --request GET "$url/myproj/v1alpha1/consumption" --header "Authorization: Bearer $token" | vi -
```

then in Vim type the command to format.

```
:%!jq .
```

But if I do as below, piping the two commands to Vim, it doesn't work:

```
curl --location --request GET "$url/myproj/v1alpha1/consumption" --header "Authorization: Bearer $token" | jq | vi -
```

How to do it?

Comment: What is the result of the combined command when you pipe it to a file?

Comment: most likely this is related to neovim bug [1496](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/1496)

Comment: It seems to work fine for me with both vim 9.0 and nvim 0.9 :-|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try:

```
curl --location --request GET "$url/myproj/v1alpha1/consumption" --header "Authorization: Bearer $token" | jq . | vi -
```

Comment: the dot after jq was missing . Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! If the solution solves your problem maybe could you validate the solution using the v button next to the arrow voting button. It allow the question to rest :-)

Answer (score 1):

Also

```
:read !curl … | jq .
```

From within Vim you can read the output of a command. You could also `:read !curl …` and then `:%!jq .` as before